# Python Data Manipulation - pd.apply

Tags: python, pandas, new-operator

I'm running into an issue trying to create a new column from existing columns. I've found that the .apply works but it is ungodly slow. Unfortunately, there isn't anybody at my company that is familiar with Python. Is there a more efficient way to do the following?

Data set is pretty large - 35 columns, 10M+ rows.

```
def state_grpd(x, y, z):
    if x in ["A3",]:
        if y in ["FL", "MI", "NJ", "TX",]:
            result = y
        else:
            result = "Other"
    else:
        if z in ["FL", "MI", "NJ", "TX",]:
            result = z
        else:
            result = "Other"
    return result

df["STATE_BANDED"] =  df.apply(
    lambda x: state_grpd(x["TYPE"], x["STATE1"], x["STATE2"]), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

pandarallel might solve your problem. It makes pandas function to do the job in multicores instead of single core**(parallelizing the task)**.

Read through this -

https://towardsdatascience.com/pandaral-lel-a-simple-and-efficient-tool-to-parallelize-your-pandas-operations-on-all-your-cpus-bb5ff2a409ae

Answer (score 0):

you could create a separate table and join it. I not sure if join is any faster than the apply method . I heard **vectorizing** function could also help.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for you.

```
import swifter

df["STATE_BANDED"] =  df.swifter.apply(
    lambda x: state_grpd(x["TYPE"], x["STATE1"], x["STATE2"]), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. It may be a little bit faster.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'type': ['A3', 'A3', 'A3', 'A3', 'A1', 'A1', 'A1', 'A1', 'A2', 'A2'],
        'state1': ['FL', 'MI', 'NJ', 'TX', 'CT', 'MA', 'NH', 'FL', 'CA', 'OR'],
        'state2': ['NY', 'MS', 'NH', 'CT', 'FL', 'MI', 'NJ', 'TX', 'CA', 'OR']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['state_banned'] = 'Other'

mask = (df['type'] == 'A3') & (df['state1'].isin(['FL', 'MI', 'NJ', 'TX']))
df['state_banned'][mask] = df['state1'][mask]

mask = (df['type'] != 'A3') & (df['state2'].isin(['FL', 'MI', 'NJ', 'TX']))
df['state_banned'][mask] = df['state2'][mask]
```

Comment: Pramote's suggestion was much faster. Went from taking 20 minutes to run to around 1 minute.